# Ошибка в коде Python (Массивы и циклы)

Tags: python, массивы, while

В написания кода на `Python` я новичок, помогите понять, в чем подвох.

```
X = int(0)
Y = int(0)
CellX = int(0)
CellY = int(1)
CellStep = int(1)
Cells = int(input('Ввести количество ячеек ='))
Windows = int(input('Фактическое количество окон ='))
CordX = int(input('Первое окно X ='))
CordY = int(input('Первое окно Y ='))
CordyInitial = CordY
SecondWindowX = int(input('Второе окно (снизу) X ='))
CordStepX = SecondWindowX - CordX
SecondWindowY = int(input('Второе окно (снизу) Y ='))
CordStepY = SecondWindowY - CordY
ThirdWindowX = int(input('Третье окно (справа) X ='))
ThirdWindowY = int(input('Третье окно (справа) Y ='))
сolumn = int(input('Количество колонн ='))
xyarray = ([], [])

xarray = [CordX]
yarray = [CordY]
While column != 0:
    yarray.append(cordy + CordStepY)
    xyarray.append([], [yarray])
    column -= 1
column == 5
While сolumn != 0:
    xarray.append(cordx + CordStepX)
    xyarray.append([xarray], [])
    column -= 1
print (xyarray)
```

Ругается на while, мне бы понять суть проблемы, я был бы так счастлив

Comment: `While` надо писать с маленькой буквы

Comment: Ты лучший, дружище, еслиб я знал

Comment: поставить какую-нибудь питоновскую IDE и в ней код писать - ошибки будут хотя бы подсвечиваться и подписываться в чем именно они заключаются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while` надо писать с маленькой буквы

```
сolumn = int(input('Количество колонн =')
```

буква `с` русская а должна быть английской `c`

регистр имеет значение. Вы создали переменные `CordX` и `CordY` а используете `cordx` и `cordy`

писать `int(0)` не обязательно можно просто `0`

```
column == 5
```

вы просто сравнили два значения, чтобы присвоить значение используйте `=`

```
column = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

while нужно писать с маленькой буквы

Comment: да там половина переменных с разными буквами - посмотрите например на `cordy` :), а также посмотрите на `column` который в `while` и выше